# Partial update doesn't work with primefaces 4.0 and IE9 in compatibility view

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Simple login page doesn't show growl message in IE9 in compatibility view.

The code is:

```
<p:commandButton id="login_button" value="Login" 
   actionListener="#{logonBean.login}" update="@form"/>
```

The ajax request is broken and looks like:

`javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=login_Form%3Alogin_button&javax.faces.partial.execute=%40all&javax.faces.partial.render=undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined&login_Form`

If I specify `partialSubmit="false"` nothing is changed.

For [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) everything works perfect.

In normal mode all is ok as well as for Chrome and FireFox browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default IE9 in compatibility view works as IE7.

And IE7 is no more supported by Primefaces [(since version 3.5)](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2408).

Compatibility version can be changed via Developer Tools -> Browser Mode to IE8 as the minimal version of browser supported by Primefaces.

I couldn't figure out how to change it by default to IE8 (most likely by fixing registry).
Also native IE8 works a little bit different from the one in compatibility view (for instance, the attribute `target="_blank"` in native mode opens a new window, but in compatibility view it opens a new tab).

So for testing purposes the way is to install a Virtual PC with Windows XP Mode and test application for compatibility issues with the native IE8 browser.